# DriveApp.getFoldersByName on android tablet/phone permissions problem

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The problem is that my script runs well on windows PC, but when I run the same script on Android phone/tablet, i get:

You do not have permission to call DriveApp.getFoldersByName. Required permissions: (https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly || https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive) at ....

These scopes are included in appscript.json

```
"oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.currentonly", 
              "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets", 
              "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly",
              "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

I didn't find such kind of restrictions, using mobile OS.

This is the row which throws the error:

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(searchedFolder).next().getId();
```

Comment: Guys, sory, this is my first question. I use this with onEdit trigger, which doesn't allow such functions which needs user permissions. I think this is my problem :)

Comment: You're right, that'll be your problem if you're just using `onEdit` simple trigger. You should be able to get this working by using an installable `onEdit` trigger though, [check the documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) for how to achieve this.